# jQuery Tree expand node based on log-in

Tags: jquery, treeview

has anyone implemented a jQuery Treeview (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview) that will expand a specific node based on a user login role? I'm hoping that a user with UserRole2 have "Node2" expanded on the tree when they login. I'm not sure where to begin with this and so far searches have come up null. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm not sure where to begin with this"

I suggest writing down the steps on paper...

You want to do something *in the browser* after some other action *on the server* has completed. Maybe you could inject a bit of script that says "on page load, expand this node" and tell it what node to expand on page load.